# Adding Indicator to Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I have a carousel set up. I need to add indicators on the bottom to show the user which slide they are on. I've read that using bootstrap scrollspy can work, but tried it and it wasn't successful.

How can I use scrollspy for this? Or is there a better way, and how?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXBjJ)

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li class="hideable" style="display: block;" id="section1">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
    </li>
    <li class="hideable"  id="section2">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
    </li>
    <li class="hideable"  id="section3">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/300x100"/>
    </li>
    <li class="hideable"  id="section4">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/400x100"/>
    </li>
    <li class="hideable">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/500x100"/>
    </li>
    <li class="hideable">
        <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/600x100"/>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you give us more detail about this "button" since you don't have one in your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) rather than a slider.

Comment: Isn't there another way to make indicators without having to resort to bootstrap's carousel?

Comment: The reason I don't want to use bootstrap's carousel is because it freezes when I delete a slide. Try it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpJLWE

Comment: Weird, I played around with it for a while and couldn't fix the freezing. You could potentially create a scroll box in html, pack your slides into divs within said scroll box, then use scroll spy to navigate to those divs.